# Events to send mail in Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, events, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I am trying to implement Events in Laravel 5.1. The event when fired will send a mail.

I did the following steps:

First, in EventServiceProvider, I added this in `$listen`

```
'send.mail' => [
            \App\Listeners\CreateTicketMail::class,
        ],
```

Second, created a new Event class - `SendActionEmails`.

And then a handler for this event in Listener class - CreateTicketMail

```
public function handle(SendActionEmails $event)
{
    dd($event);
}
```

Now when I fire this event `send.mail`, I get an error

```
Event::fire('check.fire');

Argument 1 passed to App\Listeners\CreateTicketMail::handle() must be an instance of App\Events\SendActionEmails, none given
```

Also, where can I send the data to the Event which will be used by the Mail. Data like to, from, subject.

One way I found that when firing event, passing as argument to the fire.

```
Event::fire('check.fire', array($data));
```

But, how do I handle this data in listener????

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass event object to fire method and listen to an event named like the event class:

In EventServiceProvider:

```
SendActionEmails::class => [
    \App\Listeners\CreateTicketMail::class,
],
```

Event class:

```
class SendActionEmails {
  public $data;
}
```

Fire event and pass some data:

```
$event = new SendActionEmails;
$event->data = 'some data';
Event::fire($event);
```